# Error in cudaMemcpyToSymbol using CUDA 5

Tags: c, cuda, gpu-constant-memory

**The Problem**

I have prepared one sample CUDA code using the constant memory. I can run this in cuda 4.2 successfully but I get  *"invalid device symbol"* when I compile using the CUDA 5.
I have attached the sample code here.

**The Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>

struct CParameter
{
    int A;  
    float B;
    float C;
    float D;
};

__constant__ CParameter * CONSTANT_PARAMETER;   
#define PARAMETER "CONSTANT_PARAMETER"

bool ERROR_CHECK(cudaError_t Status)
{
    if(Status != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf(cudaGetErrorString(Status));
        return false;
    }   
    return true;
}

// Kernel that executes on the CUDA device
__global__ void square_array(float *a, int N)
{
  int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (idx<N)
  {
      a[idx] = CONSTANT_PARAMETER->A * a[idx];
  }
}
////Main Function/////
int main(void)
{
    /////Variable Definition
    const int N = 10;
    size_t size = N * sizeof(float);
    cudaError_t Status = cudaSuccess;

    CParameter * m_dParameter;
    CParameter * m_hParameter;
    float * m_D;
    float * m_H;

    //Memory Allocation Host
    m_hParameter = new CParameter;
    m_H = new float[N];

    //Memory Allocation Device
    cudaMalloc((void **) &m_D, size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&m_dParameter,sizeof(CParameter));

    ////Data Initialization
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
        m_H[i] = (float)i;

    m_hParameter->A = 5;
    m_hParameter->B = 3;
    m_hParameter->C = 98;
    m_hParameter->D = 100;

    //Memory Copy from Host To Device
    Status = cudaMemcpy(m_D, m_H, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    ERROR_CHECK(Status);

    Status = cudaMemcpy(m_dParameter,m_hParameter,sizeof(CParameter),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    ERROR_CHECK(Status);        

    Status = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(PARAMETER, &m_dParameter, sizeof(m_dParameter));
    ERROR_CHECK(Status);

    // Do calculation on device:
    int block_size = 4;

    int n_blocks = N/block_size + (N%block_size == 0 ? 0:1);

    square_array <<<n_blocks, block_size>>>(m_D,N);

    // Retrieve result from device and store it in host array
    cudaMemcpy(m_H, m_D, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Print results
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf("%d %f\n", i, m_H[i]);

    // Cleanup
    free(m_H);
    free(m_hParameter);
    cudaFree(m_dParameter);
    cudaFree(m_D);
    return 0;   
}
```

**I have tried *WINDOWS: CUDA 5.0 Production Release* and the Graphics card is GTX 590.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have added an example to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16045453/596547

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In an effort to avoid being ["Stringly Typed"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html), the use of character strings to refer to device symbols was deprecated in CUDA runtime API functions in CUDA 4.1, and removed in CUDA 5.0.

The [CUDA 5 release notes](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_0/rel/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes_And_Errata.txt) read:

> **  The use of a character string to indicate a device symbol, which was possible 
>   with certain API functions, is no longer supported. Instead, the symbol should be 
>   used directly.

If you change your code to the following, it should work.

```
Status = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(CONSTANT_PARAMETER, &m_dParameter, sizeof(m_dParameter));
ERROR_CHECK(Status);
```

[image]

Comment: I have added an example about this topic http://stackoverflow.com/a/16045453/596547

Answer (score 10):

From the [CUDA 5.0 Release Notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html):

> ** The use of a character string to indicate a device symbol, which was possible with certain API functions, is no longer supported. Instead, the symbol should be used directly. "

These API functions still exist, but they accept the target symbol argument only as a bare identifier now, not as either a bare identifier or a string literal naming an ident. E.g.

```
__ device__ __ constant__ type ident;

main() { cudaMemcpyToSymbol("ident", ...); } // no longer valid, returns cudaErrorInvalidSymbol

main() { cudaMemcpyToSymbol(ident, ...); }   // valid
```

So get rid of this:

```
#define PARAMETER "CONSTANT_PARAMETER"
```

And change this:

```
Status = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(PARAMETER, &m_dParameter, sizeof(m_dParameter));
```

To this:

```
Status = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(CONSTANT_PARAMETER, &m_dParameter, sizeof(m_dParameter));
```

And I think it will work.

Comment: My answer was first and includes a kitty. :)

Comment: SO should have a badge "good kitty: first lolcat answer with score of at least 1"