# cudaMemcpyToSymbol: zero value in __constant__ variable

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I saw many answers on the same question, but never find the solution. Only some recommendations to use char simbol in cudaMemcpyToSymbol(...) etc.

I created new CUDA project (VS2012+CUDA 6.0) using this 100% working code from [cudaMemcpyToSymbol using or not using string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435880/cudamemcpytosymbol-using-or-not-using-string/24769220?noredirect=1#comment38436260_24769220)

```
//file: main.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>

__constant__ float constData[256];
__device__ float devData;
__device__ float* devPointer;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  cudaFree(0);

  float data[256];

  /**>>>>>>>**/   data[0] = 1.0f; 

  cudaError_t err = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(constData, data, sizeof(data));
  printf("Err id: %d, str: %s\n", err, cudaGetErrorString(err));

  /**>>>>>>>**/   printf("constData[0]: %f ", constData[0]);

  float value = 3.14f;
  err = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(devData, &value, sizeof(float));
  printf("Err id: %d, str: %s\n", err, cudaGetErrorString(err));

  /**>>>>>>>**/   printf("devData: %f ", devData);

  float* ptr;
  cudaMalloc(&ptr, 256 * sizeof(float));
  err = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(devPointer, &ptr, sizeof(ptr));
  printf("Err id: %d, str: %s\n", err, cudaGetErrorString(err));
  cudaFree(ptr);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And I have 2 unresolved problems:

1. The error "invalid device symbol" at runtime if not
   "compute_10,sm_10" in project properties.
2. Debugger and printf show, that constData[0] = 0.000000 and devData = 0.000000

Please give me some comments, what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I compile this code, I get 2 warnings:

```
t481.cu(20): warning: a __constant__ variable "constData" cannot be directly read in a host function
t481.cu(26): warning: a __device__ variable "devData" cannot be directly read in a host function
```

You should not ignore these warnings.  Even though they are "warnings", they represent significant problems in your code.  Line 20 looks like this:

```
/**>>>>>>>**/   printf("constData[0]: %f ", constData[0]);
```

`constData` is a variable that lives on the device. You **cannot** access such a variable in ordinary host code (such as passing it to `printf`).  That is a general rule in CUDA: device variables cannot be used in ordinary host code, and host variables cannot be used in ordinary device code.

Line 26 is similar.  Those lines aren't really doing much for us anyway, so let's get rid of them.  If you want to print out the values from lines 20 and 26, you would need to copy those values *back to the host* (e.g. using `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol()`), before printing.

Apart from that, your program runs for me without any errors *if I compile for the correct GPU architecture*. The invalid device symbol error you are seeing is due to the fact that your device is a cc1.0 device, which requires `compute_10, sm_10` code generation.  If you compile for another (higher) architecture, your kernel will not load because the device code does not match your architecture.  Since there is no matching device code, the static device variables, including your `__constant__` variable, do not get instantiated.  Because they are not instantiated, the symbol is not valid, and this is the first indication in your program that something is wrong.

So you need to compile for a GPU architecture which matches your device.

Comment: This makes me wonder why it is only a warning and not an error when yo try to directly read `__constant__` variables from host code.